# Irreducible polynomial with given discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ a field and let $D$ an element of an extension $K/F$ such that $D$ is not the square of any element of $F$. Does there exists an irreducible polynomial in $F[X]$ with discriminant $D$? Are there sufficient conditions for such polynomial to exists e.g. $char F\neq 2$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{D}\in K$?

Comment: @AlexBecker Not necessarily but if the statement is true under some conditions it might be one them. It is not an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If $D\notin F$, then such a polynomial will never exist. The discriminant of a polynomial $f\in F[x]$ is a polynomial function of the coefficients of $f$. Hence, $disc(f)\in K$.